# Forced Updated Display view controller from .xib

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, xib

I am attempting to display a view controller from .xib that indicates to a user that an update to the app is available. For some reason, the following code seems to do nothing:

```
if ([serverObject[@"newServerBuilt"] isEqualToString:@"YES"])    {


                //we want to display the text from the server to user
                NSString * displayText=serverObject[@"displayText"];

                ForceUpdate * forceUpdateViewController = [[ForceUpdate alloc] initWithNibName:@"ForceUpdate" bundle:nil];

                forceUpdateViewController.textToShow=displayText;

                [self presentViewController:forceUpdateViewController    animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

Does anyone know why? As you can see, I'm allowing myself to display an update view controller based upon a customizable message on the server.

Also, when I click on a textlabel in the .xib, it says the textlabel connects to the "File's ownder" but should it connect to "Forced Update"?

and the forced update.h looks like so:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ForceUpdate : UIView

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * textToShow;

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you would be doing it in `AppDelegate.m` file. if `YES` then you need to presentViewController from `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController]` insetead `self`.

```
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController] presentViewController:forceUpdateViewController    animated:NO completion:nil];
```